# IOS multiple targets, with each target linking its own architecture static lib..?

Tags: ios5, xcode4

I'm running into the following problem. From a 3rd party i need to add 2 different (static) libraries: 1 for the Simulator and 1 for the Device (same name libIKEA.a, but different architecture).

So i was thinking to have one target for the Simulator with its specific lib and one target for the Device. But i can't get it to work.

If i duplicate the target (simulator), which works fine, and change the lib (Build Phase -> Link Libraries), the project doesn't want to compile anymore.

```
Ignoring file ..../Debug-iphonesimulator/libIKEA.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
```

I also tried dragging the 2 different lib into the project, and selecting **one** target for each target.

I like to build (and run) just one specific target, based on the active scheme.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: ok so IKEA is making an app for what, teaching customers how to build their furniture ?

Comment: your serious? libIKEA is a library for bluetooth scanners (Koamtac).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it.

Just make separate folders inside your project folder, copy the lib (.a) inside each of these folders. Then under build setting make sure for each build you only included the search path to one of the libs.